# Glut + MinGW

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Здравствуйте!
Я изучаю в данный момент C++. Установил себе MinGW и создал батник (.bat) для компиляции с таким содержанием :

```
 g++ main.cpp -o main
 Pause
 main
```

Вот такой велосипед...Но я как бы только учусь... :)
Вроде все было в порядке. Все компилируется , но в какой то момент мне захотелось попробовать поковырять OpenGl и тому подобное. Так как я не сильно силен в API я набрел на Glut. Вот тут и начались мои проблемы.

Уже день точно копаю интернет ничего не попалось до сих пор. Установил кучу всяких либ , фриглутов , сборок для mingw - не работает и всё тут. Выдаёт кучу всяких ошибок с заявлением что что то не объявленно. Помогите пожалуйста прицепить его. Если можно подробно. Или на статью дайте ссылку. И какие аргументы нужно передать для компиляции?

ps. Работаю под Windows. Компилирую MinGW через батник выше. Пишу в notepad++ :). IDE не предлагать , я думаю это хороший опыт - пусть и мазахизм....

pps. Извините если что то не понятно объяснил - напишите в комментариях , постараюсь исправить...

Спасибо заранее...

Comment: Возможно, это поможет: [C++ ошибка glut.h](http://hashcode.ru/questions/72953/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-glut-h)

Comment: Да что то похоже...Почитаю , спасибо :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как подключить библиотеки opengl и glut?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132537/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-opengl-%d0%b8-glut)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, батник - это устаревший убогий метод компиляции. Нормальные умные люди придумали makefile, которые очень просто пишутся и очень просто используются. Это позволяет компилировать только те части программы, которые реально изменились. Да и компиляция-запуск-инсталляция программы выполняются практически одной командой (`make`).

Во-вторых, явно нужно подключить библиотеки GLUT к программе, иначе компоновщик связей (линкер) не будет видеть код ф-ций.
Вот, например, строка запуска компилятора для компиляции тестовой программы из комплекта библиотек GLUT. Обратите внимание на параметры `-LGLUT32 -LOPENGL32 -LGLU32`:

> g++ -o progs/mesademos/gears.exe progs/mesademos/gears.c -mthreads -std=c++0x -O3 -lglut32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -mwindows -enable-auto-import
>       progs/mesademos/gears.exe

Второй вариант командной строки:

> g++ -o test -Wall test.c -mwindows glut32.lib -lopengl32 -lglu32

Отличие только в том, что явно подцепляется файл `glut32.lib`

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю про makefile (хотя что то я про него уже слышал). А про параметры - я наверно все уже перебрал которые относятся к OpenGl и к Glut не хочет он работать...А вы могли бы дать ссылку где достать glut. Заранее спасибо...

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/ ?
Конкретно для mingw32 есть еще такая ссылка - https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/help/cpp_mingw-glut-setup.php

Comment: Эм...Для MinGW...Там вроде другой , не?

Comment: Да нет. Вроде везде одинаковые.

Comment: Я качал с другого места...У MinGW .a либы имеют расширение я так понял...

Comment: Необязательно.

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало :). Извините , вы не знаете где можно получить информацию по этим параметрам которые передаются компилятору?..Ещё раз спасибо сработал тот метод с явным подцеплением ^^

Comment: Вообще Mingw32 использует g++ (gcc), т.е. нужно смотреть опции командной строки gcc. Это можно сделать [здесь][1].

 [1]: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.1/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html