# Как подключить библиотеки opengl и glut?

Tags: glut, c++, opengl

Что нужно написать в `#include <....>`?

Comment: Лучше сразу изучайте glew и glfw это тоже что и glut только современние.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для подключения **заголовков**:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Библиотеки (lib-файлы) можно указать в строке компиляции. В MSVC можно воспользоваться прагмой:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glut32.lib")
```

Comment: Насколько помню, при компиляции тоже надо указать, что подклюючаются библиотеки   
gcc a.cpp -lgl -lglut  
или как-то так

Comment: ну это если в никсах.

Comment: А если у меня нет таких заголовков?
Сижу в ubuntu , Netbeans.
Ставил в систему freeglut3 и freeglut3-dev

Comment: Возможно

    #include <GL/glut.h>

Находится в /usr/include/GL Ну и посмотрите, что в пакете `dpkg -L freeglut3-dev`

Comment: `#include <GL/glut.h>` имеется
но `#include <opengl.h>` нету и ни в каких папках его нету (пользовался поиском nautilus)

вообще как странно, в окне написания кода, нетбинс ни на что не ругается, а при компиляции выдает кучу ошибок

Comment: Ответ плох в том ключе, что не учитывает специфику линукса. В нем вроде как нет `opengl.h` К тому же указанная `#pragma` - чисто MSVC фича.

Comment: @gecube, я не вижу в тегах и тексте вопроса слово `linux`, а вы? )

>  К тому же указанная #pragma - чисто MSVC фича.

Так я и написал, что это работает в MSVC, а в общем случае лезьте в строку компиляции.

Лучше бы ткнули, что у меня вместо `gl.h` написан `opengl.h` )

Answer (score 3):

Минимальная программа для Linux с использованием OpenGL: [simple.c](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jonmc/CSE3313/Resources/SampleCode/Code/simple.c)
Собирается такой командной строкой:

> gcc simple.c -o simple -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGL -lGLU

Обратите внимание на ключи `-lglut -lGL -lGLU`

Инклюды используются такие:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>         /* glut.h includes gl.h and glu.h*/
```

Comment: а куда\когда ее вводить?

Comment: Кого/что? Командная строка вводится в терминал. Ну, или нужно найти ее аналог в свойствах проекта, если используется какая-либо среда сборки.

Comment: Да, командная строка, среда netbeans

Comment: Ну, Вам достаточно эти параметры вписать в опции linker'а. Или самостоятельно выбрать эти библиотеки. См. [ответ на вопрос][1]

 [1]:http://hashcode.ru/answer_link/10868/

Comment: добавил 
gcc simple.c -o simple -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGL -lGLU
в свойства линкера, но все равно не компилируется.

Comment: И правильно делает. В вашем случае нужно пропитать список либ в соответствующее поле, а не перечислять их в формате для командной строки. 

Эх, вы еще make не видели (и его возможности по сборке проектов, соответственно).

Answer (score 0):

```
//x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.16
//g++ glutinter.cpp -o simple -I/usr/X11R6/include/ -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXi -lglut -lGL -lGLU

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
  {
      float x = sin(2 * M_PI / 12 * i);
      float y = cos(2 * M_PI / 12 * i);
      glVertex2f(400 * x, 400 * y);
      glVertex2f(380 * x, 380 * y);
  }
  time_t t = time(0);
  tm *lt = localtime(&t);
  int h = lt -> tm_hour;
  int m = lt -> tm_min;
  int s = lt -> tm_sec;
  float x = sin(2 * M_PI * (h * 60 + m) / 12 / 60);
  float y = cos(2 * M_PI * (h * 60 + m) / 12 / 60);
  glVertex2f(0, 0);
  glVertex2f(200 * x, 200 * y);
  x = sin(2 * M_PI * m / 60);
  y = cos(2 * M_PI * m / 60);
  glVertex2f(0, 0);
  glVertex2f(350 * x, 350 * y);

  x = sin(2 * M_PI * s / 60);
  y = cos(2 * M_PI * s / 60);
  glVertex2f(0, 0);
  glVertex2f(380 * x, 380 * y);
  glEnd();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Успешно.11.01.2017 статус : новичок